# What the adjective "downstream" is used for?

Tags: terminology

I'm working with a project involving 3D printing's terminology, but I'm not such an expert... so I was asking myself if someone can explain the meaning of the "downstream" adjective in this field.

More precisely, I'm dealing with this sentence: "Handle any downstream task", which I really can't understand because it has a very poor context.

I also have this sentence with the adjective that I'm having trouble with:

> Confidently send your surfaces downstream knowing your results are usable design surfaces.

Comment: A link to the page would be useful, in order to fully understand. That said, this question probably belongs on ELL.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Without more anymore context "downstream" could be in reference to a print that would be sent to another machine for post-processing. The post-processing machine is "downstream" from the machine used to make the print in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an assembly line and the flow of the material along that line. That flow is analogous to a river, and therefore any machining/processing following on from *any point* along that line is considered to be downstream of *that point*.

From [Wikipedia - Downstream (Manufacturing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downstream_(manufacturing))

> Downstream in manufacturing refers to processes that occur later on in a production sequence or production line.